# "Until they start to singe", what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Toast the dried chillies in a hot pan until they start to **singe**.

What does it mean? Until they start to turn black? Or suppose they discussed toasting bread, would it mean turning orangish-brownish or turning all the way black?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries?

Comment: It is just the normal sense of "singe".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, "singe" means for any part of the chilis (or toasted bread, marshmallow, ...) to turn black, even the tiniest spot. It does not include turning any other colour. While both effects indicate that the food has been burned, we usually only used "singed" when we can see black.